# Add timestamps to data depending on a start unix epoch

Tags: python, pandas

I have some accelerometer data being sampled at 10Hz, I receive the unix timestamp at the beginning of the transmission only once, while the rest of the readings are received without any timestamp.

```
1540987236
0   8604,2152,14660
1   8588,2168,14712
2   8558,2180,14674
3   8586,2220,14676
4   8586,2216,14712
5   8632,2230,14656
6   8592,2182,14716
7   8592,2172,14644
8   8588,2190,14672
9   8608,2226,14682
10  8618,2210,14620
11  8616,2204,14580
12  8590,2194,14658
13  8580,2240,14714
14  8588,2234,14710
15  8608,2226,14682
16  8618,2210,14620
17  8616,2204,14580
18  8590,2194,14658
19  8580,2240,14714
20  8588,2234,14710
21  8608,2226,14682
22  8618,2210,14620
23  8616,2204,14580
24  8590,2194,14658
25  8580,2240,14714
26  8588,2234,14710
27  8608,2226,14682
28  8618,2210,14620
29  8616,2204,14580
30  8590,2194,14658
31  8580,2240,14714
32  8588,2234,14710
```

What I would like to do here is to add `1540987236` to the first 9 readings in a separate column, increment the unix timestamp by 1 second `1540987237` and add this new timestamp to the next 10 readings and so on for 3000 readings (5 minutes worth of accelerometer data).

How can I go about achieving this in pandas? I basically need a series that has exactly 10 timestamps in microseconds spread out evenly between 2 seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need integer division by `10` and add unix timestamp:

```
#default RangeIndex
df['dates'] = df.index // 10 + 1540987236

#general index
df['dates'] = np.arange(len(df.index)) // 10 + 1540987236
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta) you can write something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3    
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import numpy as np

start = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1540987236)
delta = datetime.timedelta(seconds=1)

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': np.random.randn(50)})

df['timestamp'] = [(i // 10 * delta + start).timestamp()
                   for i in range(len(df['a']))]
df['timestamp_readable'] = [str(i // 10 * delta + start)
                            for i in range(len(df['a']))]
```

df will look like this:

```
               a     timestamp   timestamp_readable
0  -0.600697  1.540987e+09  2018-10-31 13:00:36
1  -1.480723  1.540987e+09  2018-10-31 13:00:36
2   0.662514  1.540987e+09  2018-10-31 13:00:36
3   0.006153  1.540987e+09  2018-10-31 13:00:36
4  -1.305551  1.540987e+09  2018-10-31 13:00:36
5   0.204650  1.540987e+09  2018-10-31 13:00:36
6   0.264038  1.540987e+09  2018-10-31 13:00:36
7  -1.182569  1.540987e+09  2018-10-31 13:00:36
8  -1.339297  1.540987e+09  2018-10-31 13:00:36
9  -0.079093  1.540987e+09  2018-10-31 13:00:36
10 -0.804870  1.540987e+09  2018-10-31 13:00:37
11  0.238080  1.540987e+09  2018-10-31 13:00:37
12  0.647706  1.540987e+09  2018-10-31 13:00:37
13  0.578003  1.540987e+09  2018-10-31 13:00:37
14  0.972857  1.540987e+09  2018-10-31 13:00:37
15  0.414544  1.540987e+09  2018-10-31 13:00:37
16  0.127489  1.540987e+09  2018-10-31 13:00:37
17  0.942130  1.540987e+09  2018-10-31 13:00:37
18 -0.871946  1.540987e+09  2018-10-31 13:00:37
19  0.347854  1.540987e+09  2018-10-31 13:00:37
20  0.986753  1.540987e+09  2018-10-31 13:00:38
21 -0.489212  1.540987e+09  2018-10-31 13:00:38
22 -0.814278  1.540987e+09  2018-10-31 13:00:38
23  0.396447  1.540987e+09  2018-10-31 13:00:38
24  0.642809  1.540987e+09  2018-10-31 13:00:38
25 -0.209376  1.540987e+09  2018-10-31 13:00:38
26  0.884612  1.540987e+09  2018-10-31 13:00:38
27 -0.565565  1.540987e+09  2018-10-31 13:00:38
28 -1.460945  1.540987e+09  2018-10-31 13:00:38
29 -0.541121  1.540987e+09  2018-10-31 13:00:38
30 -0.125047  1.540987e+09  2018-10-31 13:00:39
31 -0.421019  1.540987e+09  2018-10-31 13:00:39
32 -0.333257  1.540987e+09  2018-10-31 13:00:39
...
```